# What exchanges trade with Unicoin right now?

Tags: exchanges

I absolutely LOVED the new Stack-Exchange-specific cryptocoin, "Unicoin", mineable by humans and unicorn-themed.

As well as the diverse options to pay for it (gold, silver, BTC, LTC, DOGE, reputation on this site and Reddit, bacon, among others) and the incredibly useful, succint and accurate legal disclaimer message.

But then, I haven't found an exchange that trades it. Is there one?

Comment: I believe this new coin is going to be a serious market-changer for everyone!

Comment: TO THE MOON! SUCH PROFITS!!!

Comment: I also would like to trade Unicoins.

My miner broke down because of carpal tunner syndrome.

Comment: Not to be confused with [\[UNIC\] – Unicoin](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=392204.0).

Comment: It's bound to become the crypto-coin with the most market capitalization because, OMG, it's full of RAINBOWS AND UNICORNS!!!!!!!

Comment: OK, no exchanges yet but now CPU-mineable, not just human-mineable - this answer has worked the best for me so far http://askubuntu.com/a/441871

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was about Stackexchange's April Fools joke.

Answer (score 0):

May be http://newchg.com/unicoin/ can be usefull but I have never used this exchange.

Comment: I think that this exchange actually trades the previously existing [\[UNIC\] – Unicoin](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=392204.0), not Stackexchange's Unicoin.